# Why or how did my code revert to a weeks old version?

Tags: git, nginx, github, pm2

I built a node.js app, uploaded it to github, and got a production version working on a server using nginx and pm2. The problem is somewhere in this process (I'm not sure where) my code reverted itself to a version that I had weeks ago that I didn't even know I had backed up. What could have caused my local files to get overwritten? I'm desperately scouring my computer for the weeks of work that I somehow lost...

edit: Github was giving me the fatal error "file over 100mb" for nonexistent files because I guess they were still stored in memory somewhere, and reinitializing was not fixing it, so I deleted the .git folder (didn't send it to trash, just deleted). I'm guessing the reversion had already happened sometime in this now deleted .git, and I didn't realize it until days later. So I guess my code is almost certainly lost forever. I still don't know why or when the code was changed.

tldr: i deleted a whole .git directory

Comment: Check `git reflog` to see what revisions you have there

Comment: I have two: 7b85280 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{0}: Branch: renamed refs/heads/master to refs/heads/main
7b85280 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): first commit

Answer (score 0):

"Your Week Ago Commit"

commit `dtwx1gmk7rx159`

Run this code

```
git reset --hard dtwx1gmk7rx159
```

Comment: Always put a warning before suggesting a hard reset. As it removes uncommitted, unadded code.

Comment: Didn't work for me. "fatal: ambiguous argument 'dtwx1gmk7rx159': unknown revision or path not in the working tree." Also my git log only shows one commit yesterday.